# Tag Fires but no Event in GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

A 'purchase' event fires as expected in GTM preview mode, however the event doesn't show up in GA4.

Here's the preview-mode screen of the tag, everything looks good to me. Or is there anything missing?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do know that prices need to be sent as number values instead of string values. If your event is configured properly, but the data is not in the correct format, it will appear as the event is sent successfully but it will not show in GA4. The "value" param also needs to be in a number format as opposed to a string format.

Comment: How to debug/confirm that?